# split a string to have chunks containing the maximum number of possible characters

Tags: python, string, function

e.g. `string = 'bananaban'`
=>  `['ban', 'anab', 'an']`

My attempt:

```
def apart(string):
    letters = []
    for i in string:
        while i not in letters:
            letters.append(i)
    print("The letters are:" +str(letters))
    x = []
    result = []
    return result

string = str(input("Enter string: "))
print(apart(string)
```

Basically, If I know all the letters that are in the word/string, I want to add them into x, until x contains all letters. Then I want to add x into result.

In my examaple "bananaban" it would mean [ban] is one x, because "ban" countains the letter "b","a" and "n". Same goes for [anab].  [an] only contains "a" and "n" because it is the end of the word.

Would be cool if somebody could help me ^^

Comment: Why would `bananaban` be split exactly into `ban`, `anab`, `an`?

Comment: More context is needed. How exactly do you want the string to be split? Because your example output and explanation show two different things.

Comment: because [ ban]  contains "b", "a" and "n" . Same goes for [anab] and [an] is already the end of the word

Comment: check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4046632

Comment: You've shown us some code. How does it fail to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: ok sorry and thank you for the tipp !!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want to split after all characters are in the current chunk.

You could use a `set` to keep track of the seen characters:

```
s = 'bananaban'

seen = set()
letters = set(s)
out = ['']
for c in s:
    if seen != letters:
        out[-1] += c
        seen.add(c)
    else:
        seen = set(c)
        out.append(c)
```

output: `['ban', 'anab', 'an']`

Comment: that is not my reading of his requirements - due to this part "...until x contains all letters. ". No doubts the question could be better phrased, though.

Comment: @jsbueno I agree, I have to say I also guessed the logic ;)

Comment: @jsbueno actually I think you're right, I read again and this is all letters, I fixed my answer

Answer (score 1):

The logical way seems to be first create a set with all letters in your string, then go over the original one, collecting each character, and starting a new collection each time the set of letters in the collection match the original.

```
def apart(string):
    target = set(string)
    result = []
    component = ""
    for char in string:
        component += char
        if set(component) == target:
            result.append(component)
            component = ""
    if component:
        result.append(component)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a set of the characters in the string, you can loop through the string and add or extend the last group in your resulting list:

```
S = "bananaban"
chars  = set(S)                    # distinct characters of string
groups = [""]                      # start with an empty group
for c in S:
    if chars.issubset(groups[-1]): # group contains all characters
        groups.append(c)           # start a new group
    else:
        groups[-1] += c            # append character to last group
        
print(groups)
['ban', 'anab', 'an']
```